# Проблема заключается в преобразовании текста в visual studio 2022. Вопрос по самому редактору кода

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

[image: проблема]

Это я хочу видеть ==> |> !=  , но вижу преобразование, как это исправить?
Похожая картина в sublime text 3 (14 строка)  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
ПС: в интернете и на ютубе ничего не нашел, банально проблему не могу описать ._.
Проблема: мне не нравиться преобразование текста показаное на фото.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Использовать шрифт без лигатур. Например JetBrains Mono NL.

Comment: Попробовал ввести `==> |> !=`, ввелось `==> |> !=`. Никаких преобразований.

Answer (score 0):

Круто, мне помогло поменять "JetBrains Mono" на "JetBrains Mono NL", разницы никакой, но проблема исчезла. Спасибо <3

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).